# CSS animation on jQuery prependTo inside the same div

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I need a CSS rule (or jQuery binding?) to animate this kind of event:

```
    $("#column").children().eq(-1).prependTo("#column")
```

What I am looking for, is a "slide" rule.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rkdLkjg8/3/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you expect

http://codepen.io/moorthyrweb/pen/pvdppO

```
$("#button-action").on('click', moveBottomToTop);

var busy = false;

function moveBottomToTop() {
  if(busy) return;
  busy = true;
  //collect data
  var $column = $("#column"), 
      $lastChild = $column.find(":last-child"),
      lastChildPos = $lastChild.position();

  //prepare
  $lastChild.prependTo($column).css({
     position: "absolute",
     top: lastChildPos.top,
     zIndex: 99
  });

  //animate
  $lastChild.animate({
    top: 0
  }, function(){
    //settle
    $lastChild.css({
      position: "",
      zIndex: ""
    })
    busy = false;
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the help of two classes that whould trigger transition effect. Javascript should add them and remove after animation.

```js
$("#button-action").on('click', function () {
    var $row = $("#column").children().eq(-1);
    $row.addClass('slide-start').prependTo("#column");
    setTimeout(function() {
        $row.addClass('slide-active');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $row.removeClass('slide-start slide-active');
        }, 500);
    }, 0);
})
```

```css
#column {
    width: 400px;
    height: 330px;
    background: #EEE;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.row {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #44B846;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
.row.slide-start {
    margin-top: -110px;
    transition: margin-top .5s ease;
}
.row.slide-active {
    margin-top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-action">Move bottom to top</button>
<hr>
<div id="column">
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <div class="row">row 2</div>
    <div class="row">row 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @dfsq, but it isn't the animation that I am looking for: I want to evidence the source and destination of the row, so the animation should carry the row in its movement.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#button-action")
.on('click', function () {
    $("#column div:eq(-1)")
    .slideUp(function () {
        $(this)
        .prependTo($(this).parent())
        .slideDown()
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rkdLkjg8/4/

```js
$("#button-action")
    .on('click', function () {
        $("#column div:eq(-1)")
        .slideUp(function () {
            $(this)
            .prependTo($(this).parent())
            .slideDown()
        })
    });
```

```css
#column {
    width: 400px;
    height: 330px;
}
.row {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #44B846;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-action">Move bottom to top</button>
<hr>
<div id="column">
    <div class="row">row 1</div>
    <div class="row">row 2</div>
    <div class="row">row 3</div>
</div>
```